# Netsuite Suitelet: Iterate through a list of transaction line items Load and Submit record without reaching Governance Limits

Tags: javascript, netsuite

I have a Suitelet script that pulls in a saved search of Netsuite transaction line items.  The user can check the reconciled checkbox on one or more lines and then click the submit button and the script will Load each record where reconciled checkbox = true and update that specific line item on the record and then submits the record.  The problem is I am hitting the Governance limit of 1000 for a Suitescript because I think each iteration = 30 units.  Is there a way for me to code this so the script can load the record and update all the line items where the reconciled checkbox = true and then submit the record?  In most cases I am only opening 4 - 5 records but updating many lines on each record.  Here is the code that I am currently using.

```js
for(var i=1; i< count+1; i++)
  {
   //get the value of the reconcile checkbox
   var reconcileTransaction = request.getLineItemValue('custpage_transaction_list', 'reconcile', i);
// If it's checked, reconcile the transaction
   if(reconcileTransaction == 'T')
   {
    // Get the transaction internal ID
    var internalId = request.getLineItemValue('custpage_transaction_list', 'internalid', i);
    // Get the transaction type
    var recordType = request.getLineItemValue('custpage_transaction_list', 'recordtype', i);
    var recordLine = request.getLineItemValue('custpage_transaction_list', 'linesequencenumber', i);
   // var totalAmount = totalAmount + request.getLineItemValue('custpage_transaction_list', 'amount', i);

    try
    {
    var recTransaction = nlapiLoadRecord(recordType, internalId);
    recTransaction.setLineItemValue('expense', 'custcol2',recordLine, 'T');
    recTransaction.setLineItemValue('expense', 'custcol_date_reconciled',recordLine, date1);
    nlapiSubmitRecord(recTransaction);
    //recTransaction.setLineItemValue('expense', 'custcol4', recordLine, periodReconcile);
    num++;
    }
```

Thanks so much for your help - I am very new at this!

Comment: Can you show more code? I.E. what does your search look like? If you are only loading 4-5 records and are suspect each iteration is using 30 units, I don't see how you are hitting the limit of 1000.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For any type of bulk processing like this, you will almost certainly need to offload the processing to a scheduled script. If you're new to NS development, this might be a little advanced, but I might suggest something like

1. Create a Scheduled Script that is responsible for doing the actual Load and Submit of transactions. Add a Script Parameter to it so that you can pass data in to it.
2. When the submit button is pressed on the Suitelet, you simply build up an Array of Objects that describes which transactions and lines need to be updated.
3. After the Array is built, use `nlapiScheduleScript()` to invoke your scheduled script, passing in your data Array for processing.

Comment: Offloading batch processing to another script is a pretty good strategy.  We have also offloaded batches of data like this to restlets in addition to scheduled scripts.

Comment: Restlets do give you some increased governance, and they *should* provide a faster response time than a scheduled script. It can take NetSuite up to 5 minutes to kick off a scheduled script even if nothing is in the queue in front of it. If you can also make the Restlet call asynchronous, this would help even more with response time.

Comment: @erictgrubaugh is there a way where you can create a custom reconciliation which will be consistent with the native netsuite functionality?

I mean to say that is there any checkbox that we can set true if we reconcile the bank statement using some script, which will make the reconciliation consistent with native reconciliation?

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding a hidden column on your suitelet that contains the internal id of the record and group the lines to be processed by the record id.  This way you avoid loading and saving the record multiple times which consume usage units and will also improve the performance of your suitelet.